# Timeout when attempting to send an email through Mandrill in CakePHP 3.1

Tags: email, cakephp, timeout, mandrill, cakephp-3.1

I'm trying to send an email w/ CakePHP though Mandrill, but it just spins then gives:

> Error: Connection timed out
>
> Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException

**According to the on-page error/stack trace**, the error occurs on: `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php line 206`:

```
if (!$this->_socket->connect()) {
```

**From the /tmp/error.log:**

> 2015-09-21 13:48:04 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException]
>   Connection timed out Request URL: /portal/users/add Stack Trace:
>
> #0 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(206): Cake\Network\Socket->connect()
>
> #1 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(161): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->_connect()
>
> #2 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Email.php(1304):  Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Cake\Mailer\Email))
>
> #3 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/src/Controller/Portal/UsersController.php(92): Cake\Mailer\Email->send()
>
> #4 [internal function]: App\Controller\Portal\UsersController->add()
>
> #5 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(416):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> #6 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
>
> #7 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\Portal\UsersController))
>
> #8 /home/user/public_html/user/mysitefolder/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
>
> #9 {main}

**Sending the email in a controller:**

```
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

// ...

$email = new Email('default');
$email->template('welcome', 'portal')
    ->from('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->to('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->send();
```

**In my app.php:**

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mymandrillapikey', // Key
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true, // have also tried false
    ],
],
'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => ['myemail@gmail.com' => 'My Name'],
        'replyTo' => ['myemail@gmail.com' => 'My Name'],
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        'log' => false,
        'emailFormat' => 'html'
    ],
],
```

**If I try just standard PHP mail it works:**

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail'
    ]
```

**Recap:**
I've checked w/ Mandrill and they say they don't block any ports or anything like that.  I've verified w/ my host (HostMonster), and they say the port is open and they're not blocking anything.

I'm at a loss.  Even if it's not possible to get a definitive answer, I'd appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction or some idea how I could even debug this issue.

Comment: Can you connect using SSL (host' => 'ssl://smtp.mandrillapp.com' and 'port' => 465)? May also help to turn on more logging ('log' => true) as described here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuration-profiles to expose the actual SMTP conversation errors between your server and Mandrill's.

Comment: @terrorbox - I tried, but same issue.   Turned on error logging, and posted the log above.

Comment: @Dave Did you find the solution? I am also getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

I hope you're speaking about CakePHP 3.x/Linux (Ubuntu)/Mandrill. You need not to change the default Email Transport and Email in Config/app.php, rather **you can use this method if you like** to send transaction email.

**1: Get Composer.phar**

In Terminal run the following, to get composer.phar,

```
cd /var/www/html/your-project-name/

php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

The above will install composer.phar in your project folder.

**2: Update Composer.json to install this plugin**

**Lennaert/cakephp3-mandrill**

In the **"require"** part of the file add the following,

```
"lennaert/cakephp3-mandrill": "*"
```

in the last like below.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
    "lennaert/cakephp3-mandrill": "*"
},
```

(or)

```
php composer.phar require lennaert/cakephp3-mandrill:*
```

**3: Run Composer.json**

In the terminal run the following

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will update the vendor file with the plugin folder, again run to get permissions,(Ubuntu)

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/your-project-name/vendor/lennaert
```

**4: Update Config/app.php**

```
    'Email' => [
//        'default' => [
//            'transport' => 'default',
//            'from' => 'you@localhost',
//            //'charset' => 'utf-8',
//            //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
//        ],
        'Mandrill'=> [
            'template' => 'default',
            'transport' => 'Mandrill',
            'emailFormat' => 'both',
            'from' => ['xxx@xxx.com' => 'Prasi'],
            'sender' => ['xxx@xxx.com' => 'Prasi'],
            'Mandrill' => [] // Don't ask, the plugin needs/wants this empty array
        ],
    ],

    'EmailTransport' => [
//        'default' => [
//            'className' => 'Mail',
//            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
//            'host' => 'localhost',
//            'port' => 25,
//            'timeout' => 30,
//            'username' => 'user',
//            'password' => 'secret',
//            'client' => null,
//            'tls' => null,
//        ],
        'Mandrill' => [
            'className' => 'MandrillEmail\Network\Email\MandrillTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
            'key' => 'your-secret-key'
        ],
    ],
```

**5: Send Email**

In the controller add

```
use MandrillEmail\Network\Email\MandrillTransport;
use Cake\Network\Email\Email;
```

In the your function,

```
public function send_mail()
    {       
        if(!empty($this->request->data)){
            if($this->request->is('post')){

                $emailObject=new Email('Mandrill');
                $emailObject->subject('Mandrill sends emails')
                            ->profile('Mandrill') // This is the profile you set above, in your config file
                            ->to('sendto@email.com', 'Receiver Name');

                $result=$emailObject->send();
                pr($result);
            }
        }
    }
```

If we print and see the result it will look like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => sendto@email.com
            [status] => sent
            [_id] => 42d1468565be448ea357cad95304bd83
            [reject_reason] => 
        )

    [status] => sent
)
```

Hope this helps your need. Share me if it worked for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You say "You need not to change the default Email Transport and Email in Config/app.php", then step 4 is doing exactly that.  This sounds like a MUCH more complicated way of just sending SMTP messages.  I shouldn't need a plugin - I should only have to change the email data in the app file.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can find that, I included the both things default and mandrill and commented the default. You can have both and call that via                          ->profile('Default/Mandrill'). It decideds which transport It has to follow. That what it means. @Dave

Comment: So unless I'm mistaken, your answer is providing me the same code as I've already implemented and detailed in the question.  Except it's using an additional (seemingly uneeded) plugin.